# linux spech to text (for german)

Tags: linux, speech-recognition

what Software can I use to convert an audio file with spoken german to a text? It should run under Linux, ideally FOSS and offline.

It should come pre-trained, I do not want to train it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Vosk](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api), it supports German, runs offline and can transcribe speech with Python. You can also use the [speech recognition server from docker](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/alphacep/kaldi-de).

Latest big German model is here (1 Gb):

https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models/vosk-model-de-tuda-0.4.zip

There is also a small one for lightweight applications.

Answer (score -1):

I work for Keen Research, https://keenresearch.com, which develops and licenses SDKs for on-device speech recognition on iOS, Android (we support Linux also).

Comment: Thanks for this answer and for disclosing your affiliation. Is there any webpage online about this product? I remove the email address per our policy.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes, here is the link to the trial SDK
https://keenresearch.com/keenasr-docs/try-keenasr-sdk.html

Comment: From https://keenresearch.com/keenasr-docs/index.html : Speech recognition is performed locally on the device; no internet connectivity or cloud support is required